# View bathymetry info in the status bar

Tags: qgis, bathymetry

I wish to view the bathymetry point for any given coordinate (e.g. as I move the cursor, coordinates are displayed in the status bar) I would like to see next to coordinates in the status bar the bathymetry data. I created a layer using WMS to connect to Global Multi-Resolution Topography @ http://www.marine-geo.org/services/wms_2.0_merc?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&version=1.0.0. The GMRT apparently contains the bathymetry data.

Another application, GeoMapApp, provides the feature described above but I need QGIS to draw shapefiles (e.g. paths) that meet certain bathymetric requirements.

Can this be done in QGIS?

Comment: When splitting a question, it would be best to pick one to ask as a new question and then edit down the original to be the other rather than asking two new separate questions. As for the actual question, I'm not sure you can without some sort of coding. You essentially have to constantly query the surface at the coordinate to find the z value since you're working in a 2D interface. It knows your xy, but it wouldn't know where you are z without a reference. But I'm not a QGIS expert, so there may be a way.

Comment: Thank you and pardon my inexperience in this forum and with QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

A WMS doesn't give you raw data, it gives an image representation of the data, so you won't be able to convert the layer to a shapefile.

If you want the raw data you need a WCS, luckily one is provided:

http://gmrt.marine-geo.org/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/public/mgg/web/gmrt.marine-geo.org/htdocs/services/map/wms_merc.map&request=GetCapabilities&service=WCS

Answer (score -1):

I found the Value Tool plugin that provides the coodinates and elevation in the side bar. The GMRT does not appear to contain elevation information. I loaded the GEBCO one minute grid from http://www.bodc.ac.uk/data/online_delivery/gebco/. I use the GMRT for the colored image which makes it easier to see the location.